# Uncaught error in rebar_core while compiling MongooseIM from source code

Tags: erlang, erl, mongoose-im

I want to compile MongooseIM from the source code but getting some error while compiling the code on Ubuntu:

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS 64-bit (latest)
Erlang version: 21 (latest)

After using the following commands for compiling

> 1. $ git clone https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM
> 2. $ sudo ./rebar3 compile

Following are the contents of the rebar3.crashdump:

```
Error: {badmatch,{error,enoent}}
[{rebar_erlc_compiler,modify_erlcinfo,5,
                      [{file,"/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/prod/lib/rebar/src/rebar_erlc_compiler.erl"},
                       {line,477}]},
 {rebar_erlc_compiler,'-update_erlcinfo_fun/2-fun-0-',4,
                      [{file,"/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/prod/lib/rebar/src/rebar_erlc_compiler.erl"},
                       {line,463}]},
 {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1263}]},
 {rebar_erlc_compiler,update_erlcinfo,3,
                      [{file,"/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/prod/lib/rebar/src/rebar_erlc_compiler.erl"},
                       {line,448}]},
 {rebar_erlc_compiler,'-update_erlcinfo_fun/2-fun-0-',4,
                      [{file,"/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/prod/lib/rebar/src/rebar_erlc_compiler.erl"},
                       {line,463}]},
 {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1263}]},
 {rebar_erlc_compiler,init_erlcinfo,4,
                      [{file,"/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/prod/lib/rebar/src/rebar_erlc_compiler.erl"},
                       {line,411}]},
 {rebar_erlc_compiler,compile_dirs,5,
                      [{file,"/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/prod/lib/rebar/src/rebar_erlc_compiler.erl"},
                       {line,195}]}]
```

Questions:

1. Why it is doing something in 'home/tristan/Devel/rebar3' path? because I have only 1 path similar to it i.e 'home/ricky/...'
2. I have even installed rebar from

> $ sudo apt-get install rebar
>
> $ rebar -V
>
> rebar 2.6.4 19 20161102_054252 No VCS info available.

but same error
3. I have tried with lower version of erlang i.e 20 after removing the latest but still no help.

Please suggest something

Comment: You don't need install rebar with apt; you are using bundled rebar3 and installed rebar2 by apt has nothing to do with it. I have three erlang versions in my system and compile succeeds with both 20 and 19. Have you cleaned build (`./rebar3 clean`) before downgrading to erlang 20?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ./rebar3 clean
```

worked like a charm. [Thanks to Reith in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779117/uncaught-error-in-rebar-core-while-compiling-mongooseim-from-source-code/51796180#comment90539646_51779117).